# What is a good way to organize service layer classes?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, api, ios

I had a Service layer in my app and, for a while, there's just one class for API calls

*Current Scenario*

**MyAPI Class**

1. `authenticateApp()`
2. `authenticateUser()`

Looking in the future, that class will be so huge that will be difficult to maintain it. Even if I group calls by the same module (user authenticate, user profile, etc.) it will be overpopulated.

*Future Scenario*

**MyAPI Class**

1. `authenticateApp()`
2. `authenticateUser()`
3. ...
4. `getSomeDataFromSomeModule()`

To avoid that, how can I should create modules over several files in a way that is not visible to the other layers?

Will some patterns like the Factory Method or Decorator pattern help me? Is there some other pattern that I missed that would solve this?

Comment: `...in a way that is not visible to the other layers?` -- Adapter pattern?

Comment: Using Adapter will I have one huge class to "adapter" to all this calls, not ?

Comment: May be the question @RobertHarvey is... How can the Adapter will reference others specific files and translate it in some simple methods call ?

Answer (score 2):

> Looking in the future, that class will be so huge that will be
>   difficult to maintain it. Even if I group calls by the same module
>   (user authenticate, user profile, etc.) it will be overpopulated.

Maybe it's time to refactor into multiple classes having these 2 principles in mind:

- Maximum 5 public methods by class (rule of thumb)
- A class should do only one thing, but doing it well ([single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle))

If there is an important number of method call to do in order to achieve a scenario, consider regrouping them in a [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

Comment: Are you saying that others layers will known exactly the specific class in the service layer that will do the job? If they need 2 classes they will handle 2 objects from the service layer? I will want some more independent, invisible to other layer...

Answer (score 1):

You have already mentioned the modules, if the code is already making sense to be logically grouped in that manner, continue with that.

It may be unavoidable to have a gatekeeper object that grants access to the modules, but every module would control access and functionality tied to it. Going back to basics and keep it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and keep it [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) help delineate those high level modules.

In terms of patterns, the [structural patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_pattern) are a good place to start exploring possibilities. The [creational patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern) should also offer guidance on getting access to the modules from the gatekeeper.